# jQuery UI Button inside table cell - rendering issue

Tags: jquery-ui, css, jquery-ui-button

I'm using jQuery button, in particular this example:

http://jqueryui.com/button/#splitbutton

I've placed this markup incide table **td** for each row:

```
<div>
    <button id="possible-actions">Action</button>
</div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Reopen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Close</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Move...</a></li>
</ul>
```

and of course I've modified javascript accordingly. However, now I'm struggling with rendering issue in Internet Explorer 8. What is happening, is that content of other cells is rendered with a bug - for instance rows have wierd height, some cells content is rendered outside cell. But when I move my mouse over rows, it seems that IE redraws/refreshes and row is fixed.

I don't have any mouseover handler nor other events. Plain table + this jQuery UI Button. I wonder if this could be happening because I'm using block elements inside **td**, or I'm dynamically creating these buttons after page is loaded and browser is having issues with rendering table.

FYI: Google Chrome & FF doesn't have this issue.

Comment: IE is always having issues with jQuery...

Comment: Please post a jsFiddle example.

Comment: It could be hard to reproduce it on jsFiddle, but I'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the markup into:

```
<span style="display: inline-block">
    <button id="possible-actions">Action</button>
</span>
<ul style="display: none">
    <li><a href="#">Reopen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Close</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Move...</a></li>
</ul>
```

Fixed the issue. The styles I use are:

- display: inline-block - because I need to control some width/height dimmentions
- display: none - because I create & show menu on demand when button is clicked